# Disambiguate to Two all-beef tags, special sauce, [lettuce],

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [lettuce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lettuce) tag currently has 212 questions.  Its own tag description states:

> Lettuce can stand for two things:
>
> - a Behavior Driven Development tool for python: http://lettuce.it/
> - a Redis client for Java: http://lettuce.io

The Redis/Java part of the description was added after the tag was originally created for the Python library.

Of the 212 questions, only 61 are tagged [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and only 57 are tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).  (None of them have both [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)).

Let's use our special sauce to disambiguate this tag, creating [redis-lettuce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redis-lettuce) for the Java/Redis questions, and leaving [lettuce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lettuce) for the Python questions.

I'm not familiar with either library, so the actual desired tag names might be different from what I've suggested here.

Either way, it should be split into two tags, adding [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) to the questions where needed.

Hungry for a tag disambiguation?

Comment: Lettuce make this into two tags!

Comment: For a second, I thought  it was about Python Salad Language.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create [tag:python-lettuce] to avoid Java users using [tag:lettuce] incorrectly?

Comment: @EvertonLenger That sounds like it makes it clearer which library goes with which language.  I like your idea.